# TransitionSet ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL does not seem to work like expected when used with two slides

Tags: java, android

I am trying to achieve an effect of part of layout sliding out to one side and then replacement slides out from opposite direction.

```java
        tsNew = new TransitionSet();
        tsNew.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
        tsNew.addTransition(new Slide(Gravity.START));
        tsNew.addTransition(new Slide(Gravity.END));
        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        View v1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.fragment1,null);
        View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.fragment2,null);
    
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, tsNew);
            if (bView) {
                if(v1.getParent() == null) {
                    rootView.removeView(v2);
                    rootView.addView(v1);
                    bView = false;
                }
            } else {
                if(v2.getParent() == null) {
                    rootView.removeView(v1);
                    rootView.addView(v2);
                    bView = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Code seems to be working correctly (but transformations are happpening together which is not what I want) when setOrdering is set as ORDERING_TOGETHER but gets all over the place when ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL is set.

It works correctly as well if two Fade objects are used instead of slides.